# Layout for PdfDocument

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation, android-view

I have done some looking around and have gotten a decent understanding of how to generate a Pdf with the native android tools. I'm still a bit confused on how the xml/view should be structured. Because for me, it never gets loaded. I'll start with the xml. which is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/dh_pdf_viewer_root"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.duethealth.lib.pdfviewer.ui.PdfDocumentView
    android:id="@+id/dh_pdf_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dh_pdf_page_counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dh_padding_default"
    android:background="@color/dh_color_background_75"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/dh_padding_default"
    android:textAppearance="@style/DuetHealth.TextAppearance.ListLine2"/>

<include layout="@layout/dh_include_loading_50"/>
```

So the TextView at the bottom is used to display my page counter(if its needed), I dont need to extend ViewPager, its just a place holder.

```
public class PdfDocumentView extends ViewPager {
public void writePdf(File file) {

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(300, 300, 1).create();

    Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

    View content = findViewById(R.id.dh_pdf_view);
    content.measure(800, 480);
    content.layout(0, 0, 800, 480);

    content.draw(page.getCanvas());

    document.finishPage(page);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        document.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
        document.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error writing PDF");
    }

}
```

I dont understand what ViewGroup I should be extending for `PdfDocumentView` or can the whole document just go into an ImageView or something? When I go through the DEBUG, everything seems to be working, the PDF is being successfully pulled from URL into byte stream then written out to a file and then to memory and there are no errors. Seems my problem is somewhere with the View itself.

Comment: "I dont understand what ViewGroup I should be extending for PdfDocument" -- `PdfDocument` is not a `View`. It is something that creates PDFs for printing. That PDF is not going to be displayed, unless you do something to display it. I do not know what `com.duethealth.lib.pdfviewer.ui.PdfDocumentView` is, but if that is a widget that is supposed to view PDF files, you would need to do something to teach it about your PDF.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have edit the question. My class is `PdfDocumentView` it needs to extend a viewgroup in order to display my PDF. I understand `PdfDocument` is not a view but a tool for creating PDF's. I have a PDF created but it is not appearing in my view, which is the 1st chunk of code in the original question.

Comment: Android does not have a widget that views PDFs. If you are trying to write one, that will take a very long time. You might want to consider [some existing options for viewing PDFs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html) or simply display the PDF in a third-party PDF viewer app.